# What does the blue numbers for my weapon strength indicate?

Tags: zelda-tears-of-the-kingdom

I have a wide selection of fused weapons. Though, I noticed that many of the numbers are colored blue while the rest are white.

[image]

At first I assumed it was to indicate either fused weapons or weapons with secondary effects. However neither is true for the Black Boko Blade currently highlighted or the one above.

What does it mean for the numbers to be blue?

Comment: Also worth pointing out that this only applies to weapons as far as I know. My bows or shields only have white numbers.

Comment: See [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/403221/291873) I wrote to a similar question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The blue numbers indicate the natural strength of the weapon was increased through weapon effects and its fused items.

I had a lot of Zonai weapons that had the effect: "It resonates with attached Zonai devices to greatly increase its attack power." All of which I had Zonai components fused.

In the case of my spiked ball weapon, its effect was: "Attaching a material greatly enhances the material's power but doesn't add as much durability." I believe the spiked ball's natural power was 15 when I fused and was effectively doubled.

[image]

Comment: For reference - all "Gerudo" weapons have this ability, just like all Rito weapons have the windburst ability. Goes to a crazy +80 with a Gibdos bone. (For exactly 1 hit!~)

Comment: Good to know. I was wondering if the Zonai weapons had other effects other than that.

Comment: For reference "Desperate Strength" (the Knight's X weapons, I believe?) also give the blue modified damage values (but only when you're at 1 heart or less)

Answer (score 1):

As part of the fusion process, certain weapons can produce especially effective outcomes when fused with other items. When this happens, the blue number appears to make it clear that a bonus towards attack power has been created.

For example, a Zonaite weapon combined with Zonaite devices would produce an amplified effect on attack power.

Other similarly related items thematically or that produce a special outcome can produce the same effect. Unfortunately this determination seems a bit arbitrary, so it may be awhile before a full list is discovered.

Comment: I don't think that's correct. This image shows a weapon that has "blue text" in the description, but the number isn't blue https://i.stack.imgur.com/6KEzu.jpg

Comment: True, but it isn't the same blue text. The blue damage number is specifically for Zonaite resonance, whereas that is a simple weapon effect, as far as I understand. I will attempt to edit for clarity.

Comment: Edited again actually, since I just noticed that in fact the weapon highlighted in the OP is specifically NOT benefiting from any attached Zonai devices or parts, and thus doesn't have the blue highlight.

Comment: It still can't be right - the spiky ball and sword in the middle weapon slot has zero zonai components but a blue number.

Comment: That certainly does throw a spiky ball into the works. I'm going to edit with my new understanding after doing a bit of research, but I'm worried that the answer isn't going to be particularly satisfying.

Comment: Ah, I think I figured it out. Unfortunately I didn't show what the effect was for that spike ball weapon. It was a Gerudo Claymore with a Spiked Iron Ball. Its effect was to enhance the strength of the fused item with less durability.