# What are the attack bonuses applied to weapon fusions?

Tags: zelda-tears-of-the-kingdom

I've noticed that when I fuse a Zonai Construct's horn to a Zonai sword/longsword/spear etc I get a +10 bonus to attack damage above the normal attack increase of just the horn. The +10 shows up in green as the weapon is fusing.

Are there other weapon/material combinations that provide a bonus to attack?

Answer (score 6):

Various sets of weapons have special perks that are unique to the set. By set, I mean the light, heavy, and spear weapons that share the same modifier and prefix (such as "Soldier's" or "Knight's"). Legendary weapons will be *italicized*. I will now proceed to list each set and its perk. I will use the following notation: Set prefix {Light/Heavy/Spear}: Set perk - description of the perk.

Wooden (Wooden Stick/Thick Stick/Long Stick): No bonus, has two variant sets.

Sturdy {Wooden Stick/Thick Stick/Long Stick}: Extra durable - same as Wooden set, but with more durability. This increase is included in the base stats for these weapons.

Gnarled {Wooden Stick/Thick Stick/Long Stick}: Extra damage - same as Wooden set, but with more damage. This increase is included in the base stats for these weapons.

Rusty {Broadsword/Claymore/Halberd}: No bonus - Slightly more damage than the basic wooden set, but horrible durability. Rarely useful outside of the great sky island for anything other than making rock hammers in a pinch.

Traveler's {Sword/Claymore/Spear}: No bonus - Same damage as the rusty set, but better durability

Soldier's {Broadsword/Claymore/Spear}: Charge Attack Stamina Up (Quick Charge) - Charge attacks charge twice as fast and use half as much stamina. Does not stack with the set bonus of the same name.

Knight's {Broadsword/Claymore/Halberd}: Desperate Strength - Damage x2 when at 1 heart of health or less. The damage increase is shown in the number, which turns blue when the effect is active.

Royal {Broadsword/Claymore/Halberd}: Improved Flurry Rush - Damage x2 when flurry rushing (during a perfect dodge). The damage increase is not shown in the number.

Royal Guard's {Sword/Claymore/Spear}: Breaking Point - Damage x2 when badly damaged (weapon durability 3 or lower). The damage increase is shown in the number, which turns blue when the effect is active.

Zora (Zora sword/Silver Longsword/Zora Spear, *Lightscale Trident*): Water Warrior - Damage x2 when wet. The damage increase is shown in the number, which turns blue when the effect is active. This effect can be activated by throwing splash fruit or chuchu jelly at your feet.

Rito (Feathered Edge/None/Feathered Spear): Wind Burst - Attacks generate a gust of wind that pushes creatures.

Goron (None/Cobble Crusher, *Boulder Breaker*/None): Demolisher - Has the hammer trait, one-hits ores.

Gerudo {Scimitar, *Scimitar of the Seven*/Claymore/Spear}: Strong Fusion - The damage increase from fused materials is doubled, but can't increase the durability as much.

Forest Dweller's {Sword/None/Spear}: Fuse Recycling - Items such as elemental fruits and chuchu jellies, puffshrooms, and other items that would normally be one-time uses are given a cooldown instead of being destroyed. The only exception to this rule that I know of is the Gibdo bone.

Zonaite (+3), Strong Zonaite (+5), and Mighty Zonaite (+10) {Sword/Longsword/Spear}: Zonaite-Powered - When a zonai-type item (such as a zonai device or a soldier construct horn) is fused to these weapons, the damage is increased by an additional 'resonance bonus', which is higher on the Strong and Mighty variants of the set.

Eightfold Blade: Improved Sneakstrike - does x2 damage while sneakstriking.

Eightfold Longblade: Wind Blade - sends out a white blade that damages enemies it touches. This is the Windcleaver from BotW under a different name.

Gloom {Sword/Club/Spear}: Gloom Toll - These weapons do a lot of damage, but attacking with them causes you to take gloom damage. These weapons are best used as fusion materials.

Boomerang [Boomerang, *Sea-breeze boomerang*/Giant Boomerang/None] - These weapons return to you when you throw them at enemies. In addition, they do not break when they hit an enemy, and have a x1.5 damage multiplier when thrown. The Lizal boomerangs function the same way.

Note: If you think of a set that I haven't listed, please put a comment.

Comment: If I remember correctly from the speadsheet with datamined info I read a while back. The "Extra Damage", and "Extra Durable" modifiers for sturdy/gnarled wood weapons do nothing since the extra durability/damage is just baked in the weapon's base stats. The modifiers just clue the user into how they differ from the standard wood weapons.

Comment: Also, for completion's sake, I recommend including the weapon that increases sneak strike damage (who's name escapes me at the moment), which (iirc) doubles the potency of sneak attacks from x8 to x16 regular damage.

Comment: @Tranquilite The bonus is x2, but the base sneakstrike multiplier was nerfed to x4, so the change is from x4 to x8.

Comment: Several of the names here are incorrect. E.g. it's the Forest-Dweller's (sword/spear), not the Korok (sword/spear).

Comment: @Hearth Issue resolved

Answer (score 4):

Weapon descriptions will often give hints as to how you can increase weapon power.

Zonai weapon descriptions can say:

> It resonates with attached Zonai devices to greatly increase its attack power.

This means that fusing a Zonai construct horn to the weapon will increase the attack power of the combination, beyond what the base numbers will indicate.

Zora weapon descriptions say:

> yields a high attack power while wet

This means you can combine a high attack material with a Zora weapon, and use (plot spoilers)

> Sidon's sage ability

to yield a much higher attack power.

Gerudo weapons (such as The Scimitar of the Seven, once unlocked through questing) will double the attack power of any material fused to it, on top of the +28 attack power the base sword has.

Knight weapons with the Desperate Strength ability will increase the attack of a weapon, but only if you're at 1 heart or less.

In summary, check weapon descriptions, it seems to be fairly clearly spelled out what weapons will benefit from fusing with specific materials. Weapons that have been enhanced by the fusion will have their attack value displayed in blue text, when looking at them in your inventory or quick select.