# How can you read the weapon icon?

Tags: zelda-tears-of-the-kingdom

[image]

Theres a small icon next to the weapon strength, but I have no idea how to read it.

The icon itself can be easy, it's the type, like sword, club, cleaver, etc.

But the color throws me; how does it read? What does it mean? What's the difference between a blue sword and a brown one?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It's just the weapon type, each one has a unique icon and color combination, for example:

- [image] for [one-handed weapons](https://zeldawiki.wiki/wiki/One-Handed_Weapon)
- [image] for [two-handed weapons](https://zeldawiki.wiki/wiki/Two-Handed_Weapon)
- [image] for [spears](https://zeldawiki.wiki/wiki/Spear)

Comment: this doesn't answer the question which is about the color , not the icon. The OP stated in the question "The icon itself can be easy, it's the type, like sword, club, cleaver, etc."

Comment: @JFL To my knowledge the color of the icon goes in pair with the icon. The modifier to the weapon strengh is shown on the number: if no additional modifier the color of the number is white, if there is an additional multiplier the number is more light blue.

Comment: @JFL there's no different colored icons in OP screenshot, every brown sword is a two-handed one, while every blue sword is a one-handed sword. I don't see any other interpretation that makes my answer wrong.

Comment: Also note that the design of the two sword icons is slightly different and easy mistake at first glance. The one-handed sword icon is a bit shorter and dagger-like than the two-handed sword icon.

Answer (score 2):

The color indicates whether there's a modifier to the weapon strength or not.

A brown value indicates that the strength is only the sum of the values of the weapon and the fused item.

A blue value is the modified value. For the various modifier see the answers to the question: [What are the attack bonuses applied to weapon fusions?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/403197/165576)

It is also dynamic, I.E. some weapons have a modifier only under some circumstances and the weapon strength value and color will be adapted accordingly when those circumstances change.

Comment: -1, it's the color of the weapon strenght that shows if the weapon has an additional modifier on top of base / fused item. See [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/402830/276557)

Comment: You are talking about values, not icons. The icon's color is fixed. This has nothing to do with OP's question.

Comment: The OP is specifically asking about icon colors: "How can you read the weapon icon?"... "What's the difference between a blue sword and a brown one?"